# Mediawiki - Transfer of empty attributes from form to template

Tags: forms, templates, mediawiki

I got a Mediawiki-form with different attributes. If i got an optional text field which keeps empty most of the time. My problem is that even when im filling my text field with an empty string by default it will not be transferred to the template and generates ugly artefacts (a missing reference instead of a blank field).

Is there any way to make sure the field is transferred to the template?

Excerpt from my form:

```
! Priority:
|{{{field|Priority|input type=category|default=High|top 
category=Priority|height=85|hideroot=on}}}
|-
! Date:
| {{{field|Date|input type=datepicker|default= {{CURRENTYEAR}}/
{{CURRENTMONTH}}/{{CURRENTDAY}} }}}
! Comment:
|{{{field|Comment|input type=text|default=" "|height=85|hideroot=on}}}
|}
```

It generates the template:

```
{{Template
|Priority=High
|Date=01/01/1970 
}}
```

But it doesnt generate:

```
{{Template
|Priority=High
|Date=01/01/1970
|Comment=
}}
```

I tried this if-check in the template but if the attribute is null it shows {{{Comment}}}:

```
! [[Attribut:Comment| Comment]] | [[Comment::{{{Comment}}}
|{{#if:{{{Attribut:Comment}}}|{{{Comment}}}| }}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that blank. You can set the default to >non< and check is the comment string >non<.

```
! Comment:
|{{{field|Comment|input type=text|default="non"|height=85|hideroot=on}}}
|}
```

A other solution is to use [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions) especially the if functionality

```
{{#if:{{{1|}}}|You entered text in variable 1|There is no text in variable 1 }}
```

Comment: Thanks, can i do this in the template? I tried: 
(ive inserted my try into the op)

Comment: Yes. Its Not getting translated.

Comment: How does the Template {{{field }}} looks like? Maybe there will by blank params removed.

Comment: help me sir. what exactly do you wanna see?

Comment: Field is a Template write in Browser URL <WIKIXXX>Template:field that should open the field template

Comment: Im just getting an empty page. I use the German versions of Mediawiki 1.19.13 and Semantic MediaWiki version 1.9.2 and even tried all German denotators.

Comment: In German version  the templatenamespace is called "Vorlage". The {{{ field indecates a template. Maybe field is a subtemplate.For the input boxes witch extention do you use?

Comment: We're using Semantic Forms (Version 2.7). When i change the input type to number and dont fill them in the form it will generate a blank output in template plus in all tables where I use the entity. But with datatype text it show this ugly {{{Comment}}}-placeholder-string...

Comment: The Semantic Forms Extention filters Null-Parameters and Drop them. You can choose. ether you modify the Extention or you set the value to something like "Kein Kommentar". Maybe you can ask the [developer of the extention](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms) for more. support